# VSCode not showing changes in source control git panel

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio-code

When I make a change to a file in the project folder, the 'SOURCE CONTROL: GIT' panel is not showing the changes unless I type `git add .` in the terminal.

They do show as 'Uncommitted Changes' in Git Graph.

You can see this in the below screenshot:

[image: VSCode git changes discrepancy]

I have quit VSCode and reopened it, and made sure to open the project root folder which has the .git file which when opened showed the changes, but after I had committed, pushed, and then made some new changes, they were again not picked up.

How can I resolve this for good?

Comment: Hey @George, did you find an answer....got the same issue :(

Comment: can't remember but try the refresh button (circular arrow) if it happens again.

Comment: Thanks, I rebooted and it went away so all good :+1

Comment: `sudo apt install git` Solved my issue in Ubuntu 20. Thanks :)

Comment: I faced this same issue. This solution works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/70428355/8730140

Answer (score 10):

Restart the extension host by Command palette -> Restart Extension Host.

Is faster than restarting/ reinstalling VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me as well. I created a file by running `touch aaa.txt` and then it showed all changed files. After that I have deleted the created file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried merging one branch into another with merge conflicts.

The problem ended up being two sets of duplicate files in git `Unmerged paths` where the only difference was a folder name in their paths with different letter casing. I used `git remove` on the two files with incorrect casing and the problem was immediately resolved.

## Example Resolution

```
% git status

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    both deleted:   filePATH/file01.ts
    both deleted:   filePATH/file02.ts
    added by us:    filePath/file01.ts
    added by us:    filePath/file02.ts

% git remove filePATH/file01.ts
% git remove filePATH/file02.ts
% git add filePath/file01.ts
% git add filePath/file02.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

I happened to face the same problem when I opened another project in VSCode. "SOURCE CONTROL: GIT" panel did not show changes in my files until I used

```
git add .
```

Below solution worked for me:

1. go into settings (file->preferences->settings).
2. search "Git: Post Commit Command".
3. select 'sync' option from drop down menu.

[image: setting option image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me. This finally worked.
Go to settings -> search for auto save -> Make the option as afterDelay. And make the afterDelay seconds as low as possible.
Restart vscode
Git changes show up only after the file is saved. This should help.