# Source Control in VSCODE is not showing my changes to be added to staged state

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-stage

I have an issue similar to one reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58467720/vscode-not-showing-changes-in-source-control-git-panel) but I am not able to solve it. I am **not able to** add a comment on that post because my reputations are low. I uninstalled VScode and removed the **".vscode"**  folder from **Appdata** folder. Also searched my C drive and removed all **workspace files**. Still after installing VScode I am facing the same issue.

Any advise on how can I solve this?

Comment: Do the files you are changing happen to be in the .gitignore file?

Comment: @JoshAdams ,Sorry for the late comments, I had troubles with laptop. I don't see anything in the exclude list in .git/info/exclude.

Even now I opened Visual Studio code and opened the repository which has .git in it. Introduced a new line and saved the file but Source Control does not show any changes or even the file that was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed Vscode and Git again, re-installed them again and now I am able to publish my new changes to gitHub.