# VSCode not showing changes in source control

Tags: visual-studio-code

After March 2021 v 1.55 update to VS Code, I’m not seeing saved changes in source control.
I tried quitting and restarting, changes appeared once and stopped again. Tried opening file from folder, yet not showing it in changes. Git version : 2.24.3

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120692

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue with Visual Studio Code in the past.

`git reset --soft HEAD~1`
on master this will uncommit all the changes locally then discard them all.

`git pull` to get latest version

Now it should track the changes, at least this was my problem with my local git.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the local repo and clone the remote one again and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are two versions of the source control extension. Check if you enable the right one or not. Click on `View > SCM` . It will show/enable one more source control section. You can find it either in the left sidebar where normally extensions exist OR you will find it in the bottom section where terminal and output tabs exist. Simply drag and drop it to the left sidebar if you need it there.